# what is difference between Reverse and Bind TCP?

Tags: networking, metasploit

i did read a lot of Articles about this question on other websites 
but i didn't really understand.
can you elaborate on that?!
this is what i read
http://www.go4expert.com/articles/difference-bind-shell-reverse-shell-t25408/
thanks.

Comment: is there anyone to answer my question?!!

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

Reverse shells beacon out from the victim machine (workstation) to the C2 server, while a bind tcp opens a port on the victim machine and waits for a connection to be initiated from the C2 server (C2 = Command and Control)

Let me know if you need anymore information.